# filter rows based on range

Tags: awk, filter, range

I have a large csv file and want to filter  and print based on range of numbers in column 2. in below example between 140 to 150:
original csv file:

```
id,IC,TT
214497,140,1
214497,141.1,1
214497,145.3,1
214497,178.0,1
214497,141.2,2
214497,145.5,15
214497,148.2,1
214497,117.9,2
214497,183.9,1
214497,211.3,6
```

result:

```
id,IC,TT
214497,140,1
214497,141.1,1
214497,145.3,1
214497,141.2,2
214497,145.5,15
214497,148.2,1
```

also is it possible to make two or three separate ranges (140-150) and (160-164) etc...
thanks

Comment: What did you try? It should be pretty trivial if you thought of `awk` for this task

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty simple in awk:

```
awk -F"," 'NR==1||($2>=140&&$2<150)||($2>=160&&$2<=164)' yourfile
```

This will print the row if it's the first row (`NR==1`) or if the second column (`$2`) is between `140` and `150` or between `160` and `164`.